# What does passing Interface in generics will do?

Tags: java, generics

```
public interface IComponent {
public void play();
public void setPlaybackSpeed();
public String getName();



}
public class Playlist implements IComponent {

public String playlistName;
public ArrayList<IComponent> playlist = new ArrayList();

public Playlist(String playlistName) {
    this.playlistName = playlistName;
}



public void play(){
  System.out.println("Playing the song");
}

public void setPlaybackSpeed(){
  System.out.println("Setting the speed of playback to the specified value");
}

public String getName(){
  return this.playlistName;
}


public void add(IComponent component){

}

public void remove(IComponent component){

}
}
```

i am not able to understand in the line

```
public ArrayList<IComponent> playlist = new ArrayList();
```

As we pass any class in generics then it allow only object of that type of data to be passed. What will happend when we pass interface, what will code.

Answer (score 1):

You must pass an instance that implements the methods called for in the interface.

This is the beauty of interfaces and generics: you can change the behavior in well-defined ways just by changing the implementation class.

I would say your class naming leaves a lot to be desired.  I would choose `Song` over `IComponent`.  The latter is too generic for my taste.

You don't show the `IComponent` interface, but it would make sense to me if it included the `play` method.  This design allows a user to play an individual song or an entire play list.  It's called the [Composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) pattern.

You have more work to do on your methods.  You should be able to implement `play`, `add`, and `remove` easily.

Comment: I am not able to understand this code what it will be doing.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually mixing the functionality and the properties altogether. Here playlist is actually a container which should contains the playable item, instead of having the ability to playing them.

Making playlist generics:

```
public T class Playlist<T> {

     public String playlistName;
     public ArrayList<T> playlist = new ArrayList();
    
     ... // SOME METHODS
}
```

Actual implementation of `IComponent` class:

```
public class IComponentImpl implements IComponent {
public void play(){
  System.out.println("Playing the song");
}

public void setPlaybackSpeed(){
  System.out.println("Setting the speed of playback to the specified value");
}
...// other methods related to playable objects.
}
```

And now you can use those:

```
IComponent song1 = new IComponentImpl();
IComponent song2 = new IComponentImpl();

PlayList<IComponent> playlist = new PlayList<>();

playlist.add(song1);
playlist.add(song2);
// which return a song
playlist.get(at_position).play();
```

That is how you can use both the Generics and Interface.

Comment: I am trying to understand what the code public ArrayList<IComponent> playlist = new ArrayList(); will do as here interface is passed in generics.

Comment: This means that the `playlist` contains the objects which is a child class of `IComponent`.